# Enable storage.objects.create access for cloud functions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I followed this tutorial but I'm stuck when deploying

> gcloud beta functions deploy my-serverless-app-1_0_0 --entry-point
>   handler --trigger-http --stage-bucket medium-post-functions
>   --memory=2048MB

I got this error

```
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.functions.deploy) 403 Could not upload file [/var/folders/wh/_71nr4c122nbw45k9zmlhbtm0000gn/T/tmpvW22pK/fun.zip] to [medium-post-functions/us-central1-projects/tutorial-228204/locations/us-central1/functions/my-serverless-app-1_0_0-stchnjlumshy.zip]: myemail@gmail.com does not have storage.objects.create access to medium-post-functions.
```

I guess in somewhere in google console I have to enable the access for something?

Answer (score 0):

Add the right permissions for the account `myemail@gmail.com` on the bucket `medium-post-functions` by following [this](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/using-iam-permissions#bucket-add) documentation.